# Won't boot unless plugged in?

Tags: boot, laptop, acer

I have a laptop which, last night I repaired the Power Jack and now it works. I installed ubuntu last night and it was working fine, this morning I unplugged it and turned it on and it would not boot linux, **the startup music / noise would happen** but the screen would lock up

I'm going to take pictures of the many different unresponsive screens but the most memorable is a black background with 4 or 5 white boxes (like qrcodes) on the screen.

When I plugged the laptop back in I saw this screen again for a fraction of a second then it booted. Any Idea on how to fix this? The laptop is a an Acer Extensa 4420 if that matters.

I just unplugged it after I wrote this initial post and it completely froze and was unresponsive on the desktop.

[YOUTUBE VIDEO](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qj-u0WG6bz0)

- Initial run of `dmesg` => http://pastebin.com/7wyYphVw
- Removal of `quiet splash` from `grub` reboot `dmesg` => http://pastebin.com/LaJLm31i
- Updated `dmesg` => http://pastebin.com/JsRxxS4y
- `fsck` output => http://pastebin.com/WNwCiX93
- Kernel Update `dmesg` => http://pastebin.com/tEBXT8rV

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1661/discussion-between-thomasreggi-and-luis-alvarado)

Comment: i can help in about 4 hours. in the chat you point. I have erases previous comments to say on space.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado did you solve this issue or should we close it

Comment: Did not solve it BlueXrider.

Comment: Are you running Jupiter or any power saving applications?

Comment: @xjonquilx not running anything, clean ubuntu.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @RolandiXor I found a blog post that fixes this issue, and it is a big one that only applies to certain model laptops. In the interest of sharing knowledge can someone please open this question back up and allow me to post the answer.